# Chrome Extension Bluetooth - On Device Available

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bluetooth

I want to use a chrome extension to give an output when it finds an available Bluetooth device. My JavaScript so far:

```
chrome.bluetooth.onDeviceAdded.addListener(function(device) {
        addRow(device.name, device.address, device.connected, device.paired, device.inquiryRssi);
});
```

where addRow is a function that adds a row to a table with the given arguments. However, this only works in discovery mode, which is resource intensive. In addition, as far as I can tell, there's no way to differentiate between devices that are available and not available. Is there an API that I'm missing for this?

My current resources: 
https://developers.chrome.com/apps/bluetooth
https://developers.chrome.com/apps/app_bluetooth
https://developers.chrome.com/apps/bluetoothLowEnergy

Thank you!